# Solow model with population growth - proof of steady state level of capital per worker

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth, solow, steady-state

[image: SOLOW GROWTH MODEL WITH POPULATION GROWTH - PROOF OF STEADY STATE OF KAPITAL PER WORKER]

Hello everyone, I am trying to obtain the requested solution as shown in the image (last equation of the image attached), however, after I calculate the law of motion, I only obtain only part of the equation that I am requested to show (i.e I only get n+d/sz part of the equation). What am I missing to do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Part 2 of the solution

I post a step by step solution, slow passages are the best way to avoid mistakes (I hope).

In the previuos answer we calculated the intensive production function:

$$f(k)=z[\alpha k^\rho+ (1-\alpha)]^{1/\rho}\;\;\;\; (1)$$

The fundamental equation, set equal to $0$ in order to find the steady state $k$, is:

$$ \Delta k= sf(k) -(n+d)=0 \;\;\;\; \;\;(2)$$

Substituting $(1)$ into $(2)$ we have:

$$sz [\alpha k^\rho+ (1-\alpha)]^{1/\rho} - (n+d) k=0 \Leftrightarrow$$

$$sz [\alpha k^\rho+ (1-\alpha)]^{1/\rho} = (n+d) k \Leftrightarrow$$(raising to $\rho$-th power) $$s^\rho z^\rho  [\alpha k^\rho+ (1-\alpha)] = (n+d)^\rho  k^\rho  \Leftrightarrow$$
$$s^\rho z^\rho  \alpha k^\rho+ (1-\alpha)s^\rho z^\rho  = (n+d)^\rho  k^\rho  \Leftrightarrow$$
$$k^\rho (s ^\rho z^\rho \alpha -(n+d)^\rho)= -(1-\alpha) s ^\rho z^\rho \Leftrightarrow  $$
$$k^\rho=      \frac {-(1-\alpha) s^\rho z^\rho}{s^\rho z^\rho \alpha -(n+d)^\rho} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$k=     \left( \frac {-(1-\alpha) s^\rho z^\rho}{s^\rho z^\rho \alpha -(n+d)^\rho}\right)^{1/\rho}=$$
$$=  (1-\alpha)^{1/\rho}   \left( \frac {- s^\rho z^\rho}{s^\rho z^\rho \alpha -(n+d)^\rho}\right)^{1/\rho}=$$

$$=\left(\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\right) ^{-1/\rho} \left(\frac{s^\rho z^\rho \alpha- (n+d)^\rho}{- s^\rho z^\rho}\right)^{-1/\rho}=$$

$$=\left(\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\right) ^{-1/\rho}   \left( \left( \frac {n+d} {sz}\right)^\rho - \alpha \right)^{-1/\rho}$$

$\Box$

Comment: Thanks for such a great and well explained answer. The more I do these exercises, the more I get better with my first time immersion into algebra.

Comment: It is just question of practice. Thanks to you!

Answer (score 4):

### Part 1 of the solution

The fundamental equation of Solow model is (neglecting the $t$ subscripts):

$$ \Delta k= sf(k) -(n+d),$$

where  $k= K/N$, $\Delta k= k_{t+1}-k_t$ and $f(k)$ is the intensive production function.   And this equation must be set equal to $0$ in order to find the steady state value of $k$.

But the first step is to calculate the intensive production function $f(k)$.

As in your result you didn't obtain the part $(\frac {1} {1-\alpha}) ^{-1/\rho}$, I suppose that you lost somewhere in your calculations $(1-\alpha)$.
As $(1-\alpha)$ is in the production function, I suppose that your mistake could be in the calculation of the intensive production function.

Let's calculate the **intensive production function** from the production function in your question, which is (again neglecting the $t$ subscripts):

$$Y=z[\alpha K^\rho + (1-\alpha)N^\rho) ^{1/\rho}.$$

Dividing both sides by $N$ we have:

$$\frac{Y}{N}= f(k)= z[\alpha \frac {K^\rho}{N^\rho}+(1-\alpha)\frac {N^\rho}{N^\rho} ]^{-1/\rho}=$$
$$\;\;\;=z[\alpha k^\rho+ (1-\alpha)]^{1/\rho}.$$

Using this last equation, making the calculations and rearranging, I found the result in your question.

You can try, verifying if you manage to obtain it.$^1$

---

$^1$  <sup>I didn’t post all the passages because they are enough long, but enough trivial algebraic passages, and I don’t know if it is worthwhile to post them,  if you reach the result yourself.
But I can post them subsequently, if you prefer.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, your time is much appreciated. I am working on it, however, I started by plugging f(k) into the sf(k)-(n+d) equation (i.e change in capital), and then setting it equal to 0. I am note sure whether this step is incorrect, or is it my algebra that is failing, but I obtain a result that is almost similar, but not similar to the one requested in the setup. For example, my results in regards of the alpha, as well as the (1-alpha) are different than on the proof.

Comment: It's easy to make mistakes in this kind of calculations. I have posted in a separate answer a step by step solution.